# KQL - Union of table with filtered table

Tags: kql

I am trying to write a KQL query to get exceptions together with requests which satisfy a given where clause. The where clause applies only to the requests table. In other words, I want to make the union of the exceptions table with a second table which is requests, filtered by a where clause.

I started with

exceptions
| union requests

and I do not know how to specify the where clause for the requests table. It would be

where name contains "health" and success == false

I could not figure this out based on the existing examples.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is covered by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer), including multiple examples.

```
union exceptions, (requests | where name contains "health" and success == false)
```

or

```
exceptions
| union (requests | where name contains "health" and success == false)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I could not figure it out from that page (yes, I found it).